# How to obfuscate relationship between 2 users in db?

Tags: encryption, hash, privacy

I'm storing mutual friendship between 2 users in my SQL table.
A row looks like

```
friendship_id | user_id_1 | user_id_2
```

(for simplicity, I chose to store

```
friendship_id | user_id_2 | user_id_1
```

as well)

My problem is : in case of a leak, the hacker would have this table, and table linking user_id's with email adresses & other user data, enabling him to put names on friendships.
Which I really want to avoid : I don't want anyone to know who's friend with who. So i'd like to encrypt / hash / obfuscate / anonymize user_id's in this table (to make it useless in case of a leak).

I was thinking of something like

```
friendship_id | hashed_user_id_1 | hashed_user_id_2
```

Is my reasonning correct ?
And if so, what's the proper way to implement that ? (i'm using PHP).

I was thinking of using the password_hash function, but i'm not sure what my SQL queries would look like when using password_verify.

Or maybe using several iterations of sha256 + unique salt would be enough ?
But then, does it mean I have to generate and store a unique salt for each friendship ?

Comment: this will not solve your problem, because hashed user id is still will be same and hacker can just trace which user has that hashed user id.

Comment: How you develop this will depend on what you need to be able to do with the SQL table. What questions must the server be able to answer? For example, do you need each of the following: Are user1 and user2 linked? List all links from user1. List all links to user1. What type of attack do you have in mind? Are you trying to ensure a dedicated attacker cannot find a single link for a given user? Or a dedicated attacker cannot verify a proposed link? Or a casual attacker cannot easily grab all the links? These all deeply matter for how you design the solution.

Comment: (For the above questions, separate what the *server* must be able to do from what clients must be able to do with data that happens to be on the server. Afshin's answer is on the right track if the server doesn't have to be able to do any processing, but it won't help you if the server does have to do processing independent of the clients.)

Comment: This might be better asked on https://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your approach will solve any problem, because hashed values can be used by hacker to find users.

**My suggestion:** Try to keep all plaint relationship data at *client side*.

What this means? it means if attacker access server, he cannot get users from relations. This means code will be much more complex, but more secure.

**How you implement this?**

This is just off the top of my head, so people need to analyze this more. But here is a quick solution:

1-Create key from user pass: This can be done for example with PKCS5 password based key generation. Let's say key is `K`.
2-Encrypt user relation ships at client side with `K` (for example with javascript). then add `friendship_id` to your data. You will have a data like this:

```
DATA = friendship_id || ENC(user_id_2 || user_id_1 || random_nounce, K)
```

3-Save `DATA` on server SQL, so whenever you need to get friendship you could find `DATA` with `friendship_id`.
4-Whenever a user wants to see list of friend, he will just decrypt `DATA` at client side and will have list of his friend user id. Now he will send separate requests to get info for these user ids.

With this method, since friend user id's are encrypted at server, hacker cannot see them.

If you don't want anything at client side, you may be able to achieve something using store procedures. Store friend user id's encrypted at server and use a stored procedure for getting them by passing `friendship_id`, `K` from client.